# MongoDB with mongoose: can't prevent duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have spent at least six hours of today trying to solve a seemingly easy problem. I am trying to either add or update an object that is in an array of subdocuments, based on the value of a field `price_level`. Here is my schema:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const orderBookSchema = new Schema({
   pair_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   side: String,
   entries: [{ price_level: String, volume: String }],
});

export const OrderBook = mongoose.model('OrderBook', orderBookSchema);
```

If `entries` contains an object that has a particular `price_level`, it should update the `volume` to the new value. Otherwise, add the new element `{ pair_name, volume }` to the array. Here is the code:

```
static updateOrderBook = async (pairName: string, side: 'ask' | 'bid', orderBookEntries: string[][], deleteExisting: boolean = false) => {
   const existingOrderBook = await OrderBook.findOne({ pair_name: pairName, side });

   if (!existingOrderBook) {
      await OrderBook.create({ pair_name: pairName, side, entries: [] });
   }

   if (deleteExisting) {
      const filter = { pair_name: pairName, side };
      const update = { $set: { entries: [] } };
      await OrderBook.updateOne(filter, update).exec();
   }

   for await (const [priceLevel, volume] of orderBookEntries) {
      const filter = {
         pair_name: pairName,
         side,
         'entries.price_level': priceLevel
      };

      const update = { $set: { 'entries.$.volume': volume } };
      const result = await OrderBook.updateOne(filter, update).exec();

      if (result.matchedCount === 0) {
         const newElement = { price_level: priceLevel, volume: volume };
         const addUpdate = { $addToSet: { entries: newElement } };
         await OrderBook.updateOne({ pair_name: pairName, side }, addUpdate).exec();
      }
   }

   const filter = { pair_name: pairName, 'entries.volume': '0.00000000' };
   const update = { $pull: { entries: { volume: '0.00000000' } } };
   await OrderBook.updateOne(filter, update).exec();
};
```

I have tried so many different permutations of operators and so on, and checked the properties of `result`, but whatever I do, a duplicate or two slips through. It is not consistent – mostly it seems to behave, and when I hardcode some values to test, it is fine.

But occasionally, when it's coming from the Kraken web socket API, duplicates appear.

ChatGPT is doing my head in. It has suggested so many different things, and of those that compiled, they did not work.

I have tried:

- using a `Number` instead of a `String` for the subdocument properties
- applying a transaction to the code block
- removed replication
- not using `.exec()` at the end of the update function calls

It's really tricky to debug, because it is intermittent and I am unable to reproduce it by manually passing in mock data.

Is there a fault with my query? This sort of thing should not happen:

```
entries: [
    // ...more
    {
      price_level: '23463.40000',
      volume: '0.13447916',
      _id: new ObjectId("6401151cc708de7a1ff9bf01")
    },
    {
      price_level: '23463.40000',
      volume: '0.13447916',
      _id: new ObjectId("6401151cc708de7a1ff9c0ac")
    }
    // ...more
]
```

I am using MongoDB Community 6.0, and mongoose 6.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you lose atomicity when returning the update result to the client in order to add the new array element.

When a request receives its result from

```
 const result = await OrderBook.updateOne(filter, update).exec();
```

There is nothing stopping another thread from also submitting that same request.  You will then have 2 processes inside the `if (result.matchedCount === 0) {` block at the same time, and both will very happily add the element.

To prevent this race, you would need to either use a [transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/#transactions) to ensure there are no changes to the document between the update operations, or rewrite the update to use an aggregation pipeline to conditionally update or add the element in a single request.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I say, I had had a transaction wrapping this, but the problem persisted. I have removed replication so will try that again tomorrow. Writing an aggregation for this entire thing sounds like a bit of a stretch for my MongoDB skills but I will look into it. Alternatively, are there synchronous versions of these functions?